# XML: Use comments to manipulate code?

Tags: xml, comments, xml-comments

I use XML for configurations but sometimes I want to test new ones and use comments to leave them separated from the rest like this:

```
<!-- Begin testing block comments -->
<test1>
    something here
</test1>

<test2>
    something else
</test>
<!-- End testing block comments -->
```

So recently I came across an error after commenting the whole block removin the first closing comment, assuming that it works as C block comments where only the first comment opening is regarded until a closing one is found (i.e. `/* /* */`).
But when I did the following:

```
<!-- Begin testing block comments >
...
<!-- End testing block comments -->
```

I still came across configuration errors. Will this mis-comment my code or is it suppose to work like this? Because if it is I suppose something else might have happened...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-comments):

> Comments may appear anywhere in a document outside other markup; in addition, they may appear within the document type declaration at places allowed by the grammar. They are not part of the document's character data; an XML processor may, but need not, make it possible for an application to retrieve the text of comments. For compatibility, **the string " -- " (double-hyphen) must not occur within comments**.

You have such a double-hyphen here:

```
<!-- Begin testing block comments >
...
<!-- End testing block comments -->
  ^^
```